# How to choose a particular authentication method from multiple AuthenticaionProviders called by AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, authentication, spring-security

I have two `AuthenticaionProvider`'s in my application which use `AWS Cognito` to authenticate users.

first for `Admin`

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  private final CognitoAuthenticationService cognitoService;
  private final AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest;

    if (isNotNull(authentication)) {
      authenticationRequest = new AuthenticationRequest();
      Map<String, String> credentials = (Map<String, String>) authentication.getCredentials();
      authenticationRequest.setNewPassword(credentials.get(NEW_PASSWORD_KEY));
      authenticationRequest.setPassword(credentials.get(PASSWORD));
      authenticationRequest.setUsername(authentication.getName());

      SpringSecurityUser userAuthenticated = cognitoService.authenticate(authenticationRequest);
      if (isNotNull(userAuthenticated)) {

        Map<String, String> authenticatedCredentials =
            authenticationHelper.prepareAuthenticationResponse(userAuthenticated);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userAuthenticated.getUsername(),
            authenticatedCredentials,
            userAuthenticated.getAuthorities());
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No application user for given username");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }
}
```

second for traditional `User`

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  private final CognitoAuthenticationService cognitoAuthenticationService;
  private final AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

    if (isNotNull(authentication)) {
      AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = new AuthenticationRequest();
      Map<String, String> credentials = (Map<String, String>) authentication.getCredentials();
      authenticationRequest.setPassword(credentials.get(PASSWORD));
      authenticationRequest.setUsername(authentication.getName());

      SpringSecurityUser userAuthenticated =
          cognitoAuthenticationService.authenticateUser(authenticationRequest);

      if (isNotNull(userAuthenticated)) {
        Map<String, String> authenticatedCredentials =
            authenticationHelper.prepareAuthenticationResponse(userAuthenticated);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userAuthenticated.getUsername(),
            authenticatedCredentials,
            userAuthenticated.getAuthorities());
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No application user for given username");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }
}
```

Above providers use methods `authenticate` and `authenticateUser`

```
public SpringSecurityUser authenticate(AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {

    AuthenticationResultType authenticationResult;

    try {

      final Map<String, String> authParams = new HashMap<>();
      authParams.put(USERNAME, authenticationRequest.getUsername());
      authParams.put(PASSWORD, authenticationRequest.getPassword());

      final AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest =
          new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
              .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)
              .withClientId(cognitoConfig.getClientId())
              .withUserPoolId(cognitoConfig.getPoolId())
              .withAuthParameters(authParams);

      AdminInitiateAuthResult result = awsCognitoIdentityProvider.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);

      // Has a Challenge
      if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(result.getChallengeName())) {

        // If the challenge is required new Password validates if it has the new password variable.
        if (NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED.equals(result.getChallengeName())) {

          if (isNull(authenticationRequest.getNewPassword())) {
            throw new CognitoException(
                "User must provide a new password",
                CognitoException.USER_MUST_CHANGE_PASS_WORD_EXCEPTION_CODE,
                result.getChallengeName());
          } else {
            // we still need the username

            final Map<String, String> challengeResponses = new HashMap<>();
            challengeResponses.put(USERNAME, authenticationRequest.getUsername());
            challengeResponses.put(PASSWORD, authenticationRequest.getPassword());

            // add the new password to the params map
            challengeResponses.put(NEW_PASSWORD, authenticationRequest.getNewPassword());

            // populate the challenge response
            final AdminRespondToAuthChallengeRequest request =
                new AdminRespondToAuthChallengeRequest()
                    .withChallengeName(ChallengeNameType.NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED)
                    .withChallengeResponses(challengeResponses)
                    .withClientId(cognitoConfig.getClientId())
                    .withUserPoolId(cognitoConfig.getPoolId())
                    .withSession(result.getSession());

            AdminRespondToAuthChallengeResult resultChallenge =
                awsCognitoIdentityProvider.adminRespondToAuthChallenge(request);
            authenticationResult = resultChallenge.getAuthenticationResult();
          }
        } else {
          // has another challenge
          throw new CognitoException(
              result.getChallengeName(), CognitoException.USER_MUST_DO_ANOTHER_CHALLENGE);
        }

      } else {
        // Doesn't have a challenge
        authenticationResult = result.getAuthenticationResult();
      }

      var userAuthenticated =
          SpringSecurityUser.builder()
              .username(authenticationRequest.getUsername())
              .password(authenticationRequest.getPassword())
              .accessToken(authenticationResult.getAccessToken())
              .refreshToken(authenticationResult.getRefreshToken())
              .expiresIn(authenticationResult.getExpiresIn())
              .tokenType(authenticationResult.getTokenType())
              .idToken(authenticationResult.getIdToken())
              .build();

      log.info("User with username: {} authenticated", authenticationRequest.getUsername());

      return userAuthenticated;
    } catch (AWSCognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new CognitoException(
          e.getMessage(), e.getErrorCode(), e.getMessage() + e.getErrorCode());
    } catch (CognitoException cognitoException) {
      throw cognitoException;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new CognitoException(
          e.getMessage(), CognitoException.GENERIC_EXCEPTION_CODE, e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

and

```
public SpringSecurityUser authenticateUser(AuthenticationRequest request) {

    try {

      final var authRequest =
          new InitiateAuthRequest()
              .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)
              .withClientId(cognitoConfig.getClientId())
              .withAuthParameters(prepareAuthorizationParameters(request));

      var initiateAuthResult = awsCognitoIdentityProvider.initiateAuth(authRequest);
      var authenticationResult = initiateAuthResult.getAuthenticationResult();

      Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = prepareUserAuthorities(request.getUsername());

      var userAuthenticated =
          SpringSecurityUser.builder()
              .username(request.getUsername())
              .password(request.getPassword())
              .accessToken(authenticationResult.getAccessToken())
              .refreshToken(authenticationResult.getRefreshToken())
              .expiresIn(authenticationResult.getExpiresIn())
              .tokenType(authenticationResult.getTokenType())
              .idToken(authenticationResult.getIdToken())
              .authorities(grantedAuthorities)
              .build();

      log.info(USER_SUCCESSFULLY_AUTHENTICATED, request.getUsername(), grantedAuthorities);
      return userAuthenticated;
    } catch (AWSCognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new CognitoException(
          e.getMessage(), e.getErrorCode(), e.getMessage() + e.getErrorCode());
    } catch (CognitoException cognitoException) {
      throw cognitoException;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new CognitoException(
          e.getMessage(), CognitoException.GENERIC_EXCEPTION_CODE, e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

My configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;
  private UserAuthenticationProvider userAuthProvider;
  private AccountControllerExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;
  private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/auth/login";
  private static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/auth/signOut";

  @Autowired
  public WebSecurityConfiguration(
      CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider,
      UserAuthenticationProvider userAuthProvider,
      AccountControllerExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
    this.authProvider = authProvider;
    this.userAuthProvider = userAuthProvider;
    this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
  }

  public WebSecurityConfiguration() {
    super(true);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider).eraseCredentials(false);
    auth.authenticationProvider(userAuthProvider).eraseCredentials(false);
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    // TokenAuthenticationFilter will ignore the below paths
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/auth");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/auth/**");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(GET, "/nutrition/api/**");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .addFilterAfter(corsFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new SecurityAuthenticationEntryPoint())
        .accessDeniedHandler(new RestAccessDeniedHandler())
        .and()
        .anonymous()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/auth")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        // Instantiate a new instance of the filter
        .addFilterBefore(
            awsCognitoJwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .formLogin(
            formLogin -> formLogin.loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_URL).failureHandler(exceptionHandler))
        .logout(logout -> logout.permitAll().logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL))
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
  }

  private CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader(ORIGIN);
    config.addAllowedHeader(CONTENT_TYPE);
    config.addAllowedHeader(ACCEPT);
    config.addAllowedHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
    config.addAllowedMethod(GET);
    config.addAllowedMethod(PUT);
    config.addAllowedMethod(POST);
    config.addAllowedMethod(OPTIONS);
    config.addAllowedMethod(DELETE);
    config.addAllowedMethod(PATCH);
    config.setMaxAge(3600L);

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter();
  }

  private AwsCognitoJwtAuthenticationFilter awsCognitoJwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new AwsCognitoJwtAuthenticationFilter(new AwsCognitoIdTokenProcessor(), exceptionHandler);
  }
}
```

My controller looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
  private final CognitoAuthenticationService authService;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @CrossOrigin
  @PostMapping("/login")
  public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticationRequest(
      @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authRequest) {

    String accessToken;

    Map<String, String> authorizationParameters =
        authService.prepareAuthorizationParameters(authRequest);

    Authentication authentication =
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authRequest.getUsername(), authorizationParameters));

    //todo verify if above can be simplified
    Map<String, String> authenticatedCredentials =
        (Map<String, String>) authentication.getCredentials();

    accessToken = authenticatedCredentials.get(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);

    UserResponse userResponse = authService.getUserInfo(accessToken);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    AuthenticationResponse authResponse =
        AuthenticationResponse.builder()
            .accessToken(authenticatedCredentials.get(ID_TOKEN_KEY))
            .expiresIn(authenticatedCredentials.get(EXPIRES_IN_KEY))
            .sessionToken(accessToken)
            .userData(userResponse)
            .build();

    return ResponseEntity.ok(authResponse);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @CrossOrigin
  @PostMapping("/loginUser")
  public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticationUserRequest(
      @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authRequest) {

    String accessToken;

    Map<String, String> authorizationParameters =
        authService.prepareAuthorizationParameters(authRequest);

    Authentication authentication =
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authRequest.getUsername(), authorizationParameters));

    Map<String, String> authenticatedCredentials =
        (Map<String, String>) authentication.getCredentials();

    accessToken = authenticatedCredentials.get(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);

    UserResponse userResponse = authService.getUserInfo(accessToken);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    AuthenticationResponse authResponse =
        AuthenticationResponse.builder()
            .accessToken(authenticatedCredentials.get(ID_TOKEN_KEY))
            .expiresIn(authenticatedCredentials.get(EXPIRES_IN_KEY))
            .sessionToken(accessToken)
            .userData(userResponse)
            .build();

    return ResponseEntity.ok(authResponse);
  }
}
```

and there lies a problem, namely, I cannot pick which method under the hood will be called by `AuthenticationManager` in the `Controller` line: `authenticationManager.authenticate()`. I know that splitting authentication to two ways, like admin/user is not the best option and in the future, I will get rid off this one but it doesn't change the fact that I would like to create another Provider for Social's authentication and there will the same problem because so far I don't have an option to pick proper `authentication()` method. I will be grateful for suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: if your project is public, then maybe share the github link, else you should edit your post to remove the unnecessary cod(e body of the authentication methods). They don't matter for this problem. Your problem is that they are not getting called. I would like to see where the methods are placed(which class) and the configuration files and AuthenticationManager class.
  
TL;DR
Remove unnecessary code and show all the classes involved (AuthenticationManager)

Comment: ofc you cannot, because it is in the authentication method you need to decide which user type to authenticate. in your authenticate method you need to decided if you want to authenticate a user or an admin, and then authenticate that request. Not have 2 "authentications".

Comment: Maybe you can \@autowired HttpServletRequest request in AuthenticationProvider, then use request.getRequestURI() to decide which request login to authenticate.